# Does re-entry into Japan reset the three-month (tourism visa-exemption) clock?

Tags: japan, overstaying, visa-free-entry, canadian-citizens, repeat-visits

I am a Canadian who recently stayed in Japan for three month. I wonder if re-entry into the country will "reset the clock".

Comment: How long did you spend outside Japan? How long do you intend to stay if you are allowed entry, and why do you want to visit again so soon?